# как менять цвет элемента по времени?

Tags: javascript

есть такой скрипт

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    #data {
      font: 40px serif;
      color: hsl(120, 100%, 30%);
    }
    .colon {
      color: hsl(120, 100%, 40%);
      line-height: 10px;
      padding: 0 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a><span>nik-1</span> <span class="day_0"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-2</span> <span class="day_1"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-3</span> <span class="day_2"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-4</span> <span class="day_3"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-5</span> <span class="day_4"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-6</span> <span class="day_5"></span></a><br />
  <a><span>nik-7</span> <span class="day_6"></span></a>
  <script>
    const LINKS = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="day_"');
    function two_digit(n) {
      return ("" + n).padStart(2, "0");
    }
    function sad() {
      var s = new Date();
      var days = ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"];
      var hours = s.getHours();
      var min = s.getMinutes();
      var sec = s.getSeconds();
      setTimeout(sad, (60 - sec) * 1000);
      LINKS.forEach((el) => {
        el.textContent = `${days[s.getDay()]}, ${two_digit(hours)}:${two_digit(min)}:${two_digit(sec)}`;
      });
    }
    sad();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

надо определить сколько времени (минут) прошло с начала дня недели, для спана с классом day_0 с воскресенья , day_1 с понедельника, day_2 с вторника, day_3 с среды, day_4 с четверга, day_5 с пятницы, day_6 с субботы, что-то типа

```
// объект Date
const d = new Date();
 
// индекс дня недели, часы, минуты 
let day = d.getDay();
let hour = d.getHours();
let min = d.getMinutes();
 
// количество прошедших дней с начала понедельника, ДО текущих суток
let beforeDay = day ? day - 1 : 6;
 
// количество прошедших минут с начала понедельника, ДО текущих суток
let beforeMin = beforeDay * 24 * 60;
 
// количество прошедших минут текущих суток
let thisMin = hour * 60 + min;
 
// количество прошедших минут с начала понедельника, до текущий минуты сегодняшнего дня
let fullMin = beforeMin + thisMin;
 
console.log(fullMin);
```

и потом каждому спану присвоить присвоить цвет, в зависимости сколько минут прошло

что-то типа этого

```
if (m >= 0 && m < 1440) ("#0f0"); // применить этот цвет в течении этого отрезка времени
if (m >= 1440 && m < 5510) ("#f00"); // применить этот цвет в течении этого отрезка времени
if (m >= 5510 && m < 5755) ("#00f"); // применить этот цвет в течении этого отрезка времени
if (m >= 5755 && m < 10080) ("#ff0"); // применить этот цвет в течении этого отрезка времени
```

Comment: @UModeL, ваш ответ рабочий, но у но у меня слишком старый тел... ответ вполне устроил, но как его отметить, я не знаю, поставила зелёную галочку...

Comment: @Белка: _"... надо присвоить элементу какой-то цвет"_ Какому элементу конкретно? _"... начинает отсчёт в 00:00:00 определённого дня недели"_ А до наступления этого дня стоИт по нулям? И что делает, когда этот день кончился, останавливать? Все уточнения добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @UModeL, даже растерялась, когда задумалась как правильно сформулировать ответ на эти вопросы...  наверное правильно будет так, в текущий момент надо определить сколько времени прошло с момента старта и каком отрезку времени из 4х соответствует текущий момент, соответственно этому присвоить цвет, а поскольку дни недели(старт) циклически повторяются, получается что цвет будет меняться тоже циклически бесконечно...

Comment: если Вам не срочно, то завтра займусь. И у Вас будет время для формулировки. А может, кто другой успеет ответить.

Comment: @UModeL, немного подправила вопрос...

Comment: [что-то типа этого](https://imgur.com/FsQR84p) уже четыре дня назад было готово, но возникли сомнения из-за формулировки. То есть "момент старта" это начало понедельника всегда. От этого момента отсчитываются отрезки, в соответствии с которыми раскрашиваются спаны. Таким образом, все спаны будут окрашены в свои цвета, но в неизменном порядке, а третий отрезок настолько короток, что перекрывается соседними условиями и цвет для него никак визуально не отображается.

Comment: @UModeL, но сейчас при такой формулировке, надеюсь понятно, что внутри спанов должен быть одинаковый текст (текущее.время с днем недели), а  только старт для каждого из спанов индивидуальный, в названии класса обозначен день старта,  начала отсчёта...